# How to find the predicted values with Keras

Tags: r, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, regression

I'm learning keras, and would like to see the predicted numbers that are returned. The model has a number of items returned, but none of them seem to be the predicted values.

```
df <- MASS::Boston
index <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(df), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7,0.3))
train_features <- Boston[index,]
test_features <- Boston[!index,]
train_labels <- Boston$medv[index]
test_labels <- Boston$medv[!index]
train_features <- scale(train_features)
train_features <- train_features[,1:ncol(train_features)]
test_features <- scale(test_features)
test_features <- test_features[,1:ncol(test_features)]
mean <- apply(train_features, 2, mean)
sd <- apply(train_features, 2, sd)
train_data <- scale(train_features, center = mean, scale = sd)
test_data <- scale(test_features, center = mean, scale = sd)
train_targets <- Boston$medv[index]
test_targets <- Boston$medv[!index]
```

Here is where the model is built:

```
build_model <- function() {
  
  model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
    layer_dense(64, activation = "relu") %>%
    layer_dense(64, activation = "relu") %>%
    layer_dense(1)
  
  model %>% compile(optimizer = "rmsprop",
                    loss = "mse",
                    metrics = "mse")
  model
}
```

Next we set up five folds, and track all_scores:

```
k <- 5
fold_id <- sample(rep(1:k, length.out = nrow(train_data)))
num_epochs <- 100
all_scores <- numeric()

for (i in 1:k) {
  cat("Processing fold #", i, "\n")
  val_indices <- which(fold_id == i)
  
  val_data <- train_data[val_indices, ]
  val_targets <- train_targets[val_indices]
  
  partial_train_data <- train_data[-val_indices, ]
  partial_train_targets <- train_targets[-val_indices]
  
  model <- build_model()
  
  model %>% fit (
    partial_train_data,
    partial_train_targets,
    epochs = num_epochs,
    batch_size = 16,
    verbose = 0
  )
  
  results <- model %>%
    evaluate(val_data, val_targets, verbose = 0)
  all_scores[[i]] <- results[['mse']]
}

keras.RMSE <- sqrt(mean(all_scores))
```

However, none of the variables seem to have the predicted values. A few examples:

all_scores is a set of RMSE scores (which I also want)
val_targets appears to be the wrong dimensions
model$fit does not return a value or set of values
model$predict generates predicted values, but those have already been generated, and I can't locate them.

How are the predicted values returned in a keras model?

Comment: You can get model predictions with `predict(model, x)`

Comment: I am not sure if the characters are messed up, or it is intentional, but a minimum reproducible code is generally much more helpful. That being said, can you clarify on "model$predict generates predicted values, but those have already been generated, and I can't locate them"?

Comment: Thank you t-kalinowski, that works! Greatly appreciate it!

Comment: learner - very good question. The keras model has to calculate the predicted values to calculate RMSE. However, I was not able to find those predicted values in any of the variables, nor in any of the extracted values (for example, not in model$predict). So I know they were calculated to get RMSE, but I could not find them stored in any of the variables. Thank you for pointing this out.